# Change Size of UIView and UITextView programmatically in iOS Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, dynamic, autoresize

I am new in `iOS programming`.

In my application `(ios + Objective-C + Auto resize)` I have `UITextView` inside of `UIView`. Initially height of `UIView` is 50 and `UITextView` is 30 at the bottom of screen.

What I want to do is, I want to change height of both components as user type some text, i.e `y` and `height` of both components will change.

I use below code but its not working properly.

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{
  CGFloat fixedWidth = textView.frame.size.width;
  CGSize newSize = [textView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(fixedWidth, MAXFLOAT)];
  CGRect newFrame = textView.frame;

  CGRect viewFrame = _viewMsg.frame;
  viewFrame.origin.y = viewFrame.origin.y - (newSize.height - 30.0);
  viewFrame.size.height = viewFrame.size.height + (newSize.height - 30.0);
  _viewMsg.frame = viewFrame;

  newFrame.size = CGSizeMake(fmaxf(newSize.width, fixedWidth), newSize.height);
  textView.frame = newFrame;

}
```

Please explain me how dynamically resizing work with `Auto Resize`.

Answer (score 0):

You can change as per below code

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{
    CGFloat fixedWidth = textView.frame.size.width;
    CGSize newSize = [textView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(fixedWidth, MAXFLOAT)];
    CGRect newFrame = textView.frame;
    newFrame.size = CGSizeMake(fmaxf(newSize.width, fixedWidth), newSize.height);
    textView.frame = newFrame;


    CGRect viewFrame = _viewMsg.frame;
    viewFrame.size.height = _viewMsg.frame.size.height;
    viewFrame.origin.y= self.view-viewFrame.size.height-30;
    _viewMsg.frame =viewFrame;

}
```

it me help to increase your View & textView height.

Comment: I got error at ` viewFrame.origin.y= self.view-viewFrame.size.height-30;`

Comment: Where is your `_viewMsg` added ? that view you need to use here in my case I have added it into `self.view`.